# Wondering about TextBox methods

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, code-behind, lostfocus

I have a `TextBox` for which I would like to run through a few conditions based on whether or not there is an integer entered in it. My operations take place from the code-behind of the window that the `TextBox` exists in.

Under the `LostFocus` event I would like to do the following:

- Check if the `string` `IsNullOrEmpty`

  -If it is - set text to "Default Record"
- Verify that the entered value is an `Int`

  If it isn't - Display a `MessageBox(Ok Button)`, then set focus back on the `TextBox`

**This is what my `LostFocus` function looks like:

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Lost Focus
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
        TextBox.Text = "Default Record";
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, @"^\d+$") == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Illegal character in list.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        TextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

The above function works well for testing whether or not the `string` `IsNullOrEmpty`, but I'm having problems with the `else if` condition. When I try to reset the focus back onto the `TextBox` I get an endless loop of `MessageBoxes`. Why is this and how do I fix it?

**Update 1:**

These are additional event handlers on the `TextBox`:

```
//State of View at startup
private void Document_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //This is run because I need the TextBox to have focus at window startup
    TextBox.Focusable = true;
    TextBox.Focus();
}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl Loaded="Document_Loaded" ... >
```

Comment: Do you have any other event handlers on the textbox, or any code not shown in this handler?

Comment: Yes, I have plenty. It's kind of a lot if I were to post all of it. What should I be looking for that would mess up this process?

Comment: @Ericafterdark, `other event handlers on the textbox`.

Comment: @Ericafterdark start removing them one by one until you come up with the smallest code sample needed to replicate the problem.  When you are to the point where removing any of the remaining event handlers, or removing any sections of the existing handlers, causes the program to no longer replicate the problem then you have your "minimal reproducible code sample".  In many cases, by the time you get to that point, the problem is obvious.  If it's not, edit the question to include it.

Comment: What event of `Textbox` is `Document_Loaded` a handler for?

Comment: @Servy That is actually the `Loaded` event of the UserControl that the `TextBox` is located in

Comment: Perhaps a `GotFocus` event for the `TextBox`?

Comment: @ispiro Are you saying use that instead? Because I still need this `TextBox` to have focus at startup.

Comment: @Ericafterdark No, he's asking if there is a got focus event handler.  If there were, and it did something to lose focus, then the answer would be clear; each handler fires the other, forever.

Comment: @Ericafterdark No. I'm saying perhaps you are subscribing to that event and that event handler is causing a LostFocus.

Comment: There is no `GotFocus` handler on the `TextBox`. There is a `MouseEnter` and a `MouseLeave`, but these should not be interfering in anyway.

Comment: Would it matter that the `Text` in the box is bound to a `string` property in a data model?

Comment: Then I go back to my previous comment.  Start removing stuff until you get to the smallest program you can make that replicates the problem, or if easier, make a new project and copy over as little as you possibly can to replicate the problem.  When you have done so, post that code here so that we can replicate the problem.

Comment: @ispiro That also requires those mouse events to remove focus from the textbox.

Comment: Okay, I've created a brand new program that contains a window with 2 `TextBoxes`. The only event handler in this whole window is the `LostFocus` one that you see above. With that being said, I receive the same infinite loop of `MessageBoxes`. Maybe you can't call `.focus()` from a `LostFocus` event handler...

Comment: I am able to replicate it (sort of - it only happens 3 times~). (Winforms) Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do not attempt to set focus from within the Enter, GotFocus, Leave,
>   LostFocus, Validating, or Validated event handlers. Doing so can cause
>   your application or the operating system to stop responding...

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#alert_caution)

Comment: Then how am I ever supposed to base these actions off of the user leaving the `TextBox`?

Comment: @Ericafterdark You aren't.  That's the point.  Regardless, it's really poor user design to prevent them from removing focus from the textbox until it's fixed.  Just prevent them from performing any actions that depend on that textbox having a valid value (i.e. disable related buttons) instead of forcing focus on the textbox.

Comment: @Servy I gotcha. I'll have to redesign a little, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to reset the focus back onto the TextBox I get an endless
>   loop of `MessageBoxes`

This happens because you're invoking the focus to the TextBox control, just when the event `LostFocus` is raised. When you close the MessageBox, the TextBox control got the focus, but the event `LostFocus` is continuously raised, and, because the `else` condition is satisfied, you will have an endless loop with the MessageBoxes.

I think you shouldn't use the event `LostFocus` to check the value of the TextBox and focus again. Have you considered the event [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

You could then do something like this:

```
private void TextTest_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Text changed");

      /*  your logic here */   

      TextTest.Focus(); //it could be useless in this case!
}
```

Comment: Where it says `your logic here`, do I have to change anything?

Comment: First, this won't cause a stack overflow exception.  The stack is not increasing.  It just goes forever.  Next, the code shown doesn't indicate how setting focus results in the focus being lost again, which needs to happen for there to be an infinite loop.

Comment: @Servy Yes, you're right. I tested a wrong piece of code. My fault. My answer is updated.

Comment: @Ericafterdark You should replace the comment with your logic, used to check the input of the user in your TextBox.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano It's still not right.  If you set focus whenever focus is lost then you can never focus anything else (which, granted, is poor user design) but unless focusing the object again results in focus being lost, the "lost focus" handler isn't fired a second time, so there is no looping.  The looping isn't inherent in the code that is shown.

Comment: @Servy I understood, but it's very strange anyway. I tested the code shown in the first part in the question with a simple app, and I have the same problem of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of whether the value has changed since you last showed the message box.
Only show the messagebox if the value has changed since you last showed the message box.

I think like this:

```
private string lastValue = null;
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Lost Focus
{
    bool valueChanged = ( lastvalue != TextBox.Text );
    lastValue = TextBox.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
        TextBox.Text = "Default Record";
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(TextBox.Text, @"^\d+$") == false && valueChanged )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Illegal character in list.", "Warning!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        TextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, with the exception that it does not set the focus back to the `textBox`. (Line `TextBox.Focus();`)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at using a masked textbox to limit the input to integers.  Then you want to do the validation (checking) when the user hits "ok/next/submit"... whatever will finish the entry.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1