# How to restrict user to TextBox if value entered is incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

In my program I have a `TextBox` who's value must be set in a specific integer range. If it is not within this range, it should warn the user and then highlight the incorrect text inside of the `TextBox` for re-editing (implying that the user must enter a value that is in the correct range before they are allowed to leave the `TextBox`). **How would I change my code so that it performs these operations?**

This is what I have so far. I am using a `TextChanged` event. This code warns the user about the restriction breach and refocuses (I would like to highlight the value instead) on the `TextBox`, but does not prevent the user from clicking out of it afterward:

```
int maxRevSpeed;

//Max Rev Speed -- Text Changed
private void maxRevSpeed_textChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text == "" || maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text == " ")
        maxRevSpeed = 0;
    else
    {
        maxRevSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text);

        if (maxRevSpeed <= 0 || maxRevSpeed > 45)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Reverse Sensor speed must be between 0 and 45 FPM", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }

        maxRevSpeed_textBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Please note that this question is a revisit of a [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939872/wondering-about-textbox-methods) of mine. I am aware that it may be "frowned upon" to take this approach to a `TextBox`, but regardless I would still like to figure out how to implement such a thing. Thank you.

**Update 1:**

After looking at everyone's suggestions I have updated my code:

```
//Max Rev Speed -- Text Changed
private void maxRevSpeed_textChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text == "" || maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text == " ") //Is Empty or contains spaces
        maxRevSpeed = 0;
    else if (!Regex.IsMatch(maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text, @"^[\p{N}]+$")) //Contains characters
        maxRevSpeed = 0;
    else
        maxRevSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text);
}

//Max Rev Speed -- Lost Focus
private void maxRevSpeed_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (maxRevSpeed <= 0 || maxRevSpeed > 45)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Reverse Sensor speed must be between 0 and 45 FPM", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

        //Supposed to highlight incorrect text -- DOES NOT WORK
        maxRevSpeed_textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
        maxRevSpeed_textBox.SelectionLength = maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

The `integer` representing the text in the `textBox` is now dealt with in the `textChanged` event. The `LostFocus` event handles the warning and the re-selection of the incorrect text value. However, the highlight text method works when it is in the `textChanged` event, but not in it's current location. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you thought about changing the if condition to check for 
`if(IsNullOrEmpty(maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text) || maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text.Contains(" ")`

Comment: I don't understand... you want to focus the `TextBox` that the user is currently typing into... and therefore already has focus?

Comment: Also, you'll need some error checking on `maxRevSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(maxRevSpeed_textBox.Text);`

Comment: also look up how to use `Char.IsWhiteSpace` function

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tried this and it says that `The name 'IsNullOrEmpty' does not exist in the current context`. I have `System` declared in the .cs file...

Comment: @Sheridan I added some more error checking on the line that you specified. To clarify, I would like to make it so that the user can't leave the `textBox` until a valid value is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to stop focus from leaving a `TextBox`, all you need to do is to set the `Handled` property of the `KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs` object to `true` in a `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` handler when your invalid condition is true:

```
private void PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = IsInvalidValue;
}
```

This of course assumes that you have a property named `IsInvalidValue` that you set to `true` when the entered data is invalid and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the user from entering the text or out of range by using PreviewTextInput handler of textbox, call it like this.

```
private void textBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.Text, e.Text.Length - 1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

The code above is for entering numbers only, you can change it according to your requirements, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I suppose you are using C#, here you can find a relevant post: [C# auto highlight text in a textbox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151410/c-sharp-auto-highlight-text-in-a-textbox-control)

As they stated the following code should select the text inside texbox

In Windows Forms and WPF:

maxRevSpeed_textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
maxRevSpeed_textBox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;

Comment: This works in the `TextChanged` event, but not in the `LostFocus` event, which I think would be the prime spot to put it. Why doesn't it work here?